# SQL Server adding values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

SELECT @s = ISNULL(@s + '. ' , '') + [Comments]
    FROM [Customer]

```
RETURN @s
```

How can I catch Null or '', so that if its either It Won't append to the string and not add a '.'

Thanks

Jacob

Answer (score 7):

```
SELECT
    @s = ISNULL(NULLIF(@s, '') + '.', '') + comments
FROM
    [Customers]

RETURN @s
```